# Alias ES6 destructuration

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm creating a generic function `checkField` for my forms, and I'd like to be able to extract from the state (or any JavaScript object) the variable that I'm passing as a parameter

```
checkField(fieldname) {
   const {
     validityFieldObj,
     fieldname
   } = this.state

   // Would be equivalent to `this.state[fieldname]`
   // But I can't get fieldname from this.state destructuration,
   // as it as already been delcared in the parameter.
   // Any alternative to this issue?
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get the field name you need to use [destructuring with computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Computed_object_property_names_and_destructuring), and assign the result to a variable:

```js
const state = {
  validityFieldObj: {},
  abc: 3
};

function checkField(fieldname) {
   const {
     validityFieldObj,
     [fieldname]: value
   } = state;

  console.log(value);
}

checkField('abc');
```

If you need to extract a property name `fieldName` you can use an alias:

```js
const state = {
  validityFieldObj: {},
  fieldname: 'abc'
};

function checkField(fieldname) {
  const {
    validityFieldObj,
    fieldname: nameOfField
  } = state;

  console.log(nameOfField);
}

checkField('abc');
```